# concatenate a string in all elements of a list in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am reading a variety file and using lookup to get the list.

```
var1:
  - foo
  - bar
```

My playbook looks like

```
 - set_fact: 
     file: "{{ "*" + lookup('vars', var_name) + "*"}}"
```

While running the playbook I pass extra variable as var_name = var1

My out put comes out

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

But I want my output to be

```
[" *foo*" , " *bar* "]
```

Comment: use single quotes instead of double quotes `'*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a snippet for you

```
  - name: Make Res
    set_fact: 
      res: "{{ var1 | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', ' *\\1* ') | list }}"

  - name: Test
    debug: msg="{{res}}"
```